# Ubuntu 20.04.1 External monitor not detected anymore

Tags: usb, ubuntu-20.04, multiple-monitors

It would be great if someone can help me. I was using the two external monitors plugged into ThinkPad-T14s-Gen-1 that has installed only Ubuntu 20.04, the laptop has AMD Ryzen 7 pro 4750u with AMD integrated graphics. One monitor was plugged into HDMI and other one into USB C socket, the laptop has two USB C sockets, one can be used both for charging and display, other one only for data. Everything was working fine but, both of monitors were detected but after some updates, after I did some updates(apt get update and upgrade) from 20.04 to 20.04.1 and 20.04.02, one day it suddenly is not detecting the one monitor plugged into USB C socket, its not even working after unplugging and plugging it back in(before it would work if I unplug and plug it back) The cable USB is good, its new and I have bought another one USB to check but they both dont work so its not about cables, it must be software issue. However I suspect the reason why the monitor stopped responding is because once I had accidentally clicked suspend option when I wanted to shutdown the pc. When I logged back in one monitor was not detected anymore. I am sharing my output of xrandr on terminal, btw I am absolute beginner to Linux. I have unplugged the monitor from HDMI, since its working but I plugged in the other one into USB C but its not detecting, its only detecting the laptop display(eDP):

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384 eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm 1920x1080 60.00*+ 1680x1050 60.00
1280x1024 60.00
1440x900 60.00
1280x800 60.00
1280x720 60.00
1024x768 60.00
800x600 60.00
640x480 60.00
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)